# populating a dataframe with for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I realise that there are similar questions to this one, but none of them have provided with me a solution to my problem.

I have made a function, which takes a year as argument and outputs a vectors with 8 elements:

```
> my_function(2004)
[1]  0  0  0  0 20 89  1  2

> my_function(2006)
[1]   0   0   0   0  83 205   0   1
```

I have attempted to create a for-loop, which would take all the output vectors for each year and convert them to columns in a dataframe:

```
ma <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 8)
df <- data.frame(ma)
colnames(df)<-c(2004,2006)

for (i in c(2004,2006)){
df$`i` <- my_function(i)
}
```

I was expecting the output to look like this:

```
> df
  2004 2006
1    0    0
2    0    0
3    0    0
4    0    0
5   20   83
6   89  205
7    1    0
8    2    1
```

But instead the for loop just creates a new column called i and populates it with the last iteration:

```
 > df
  2004 2006   i
1   NA   NA   0
2   NA   NA   0
3   NA   NA   0
4   NA   NA   0
5   NA   NA  83
6   NA   NA 205
7   NA   NA   0
8   NA   NA   1
```

What I am doing wrong?

Best,
Rikki

Comment: You can't use `$` that way, it uses non-standard evaluation. Use `[[` instead, so you can use `df[[i]]`, with the note that you should then loop over `c("2004", "2006")`, otherwise your data.frame will end up with 2006 columns (but you might want to avoid using only numbers as column names anyway).

Comment: If you are looking for a non-loop solution too, try this: `as.data.frame(lapply(c(2004, 2006), my_function))`

Comment: @Axeman. I works! Thanks a lot. However, I am very confused now, as I thought the double brackets were only used for accessing objects in lists? Secondly, I had no idea the a function takes both strings and numerals as arguments!

Comment: @B.ChristianKamgang. That is a beautiful simple solution! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could someone please post the info from these comments as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker. How do I do that?

Comment: There's some time limit on how quickly you're allowed to answer your own question (it may depend on your reputation level). Once that expires, you can compose an answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: @BenBolker. I can accept my own answer no earlier than in two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use $ that way, it uses non-standard evaluation. Use [[ instead, so you can use df[[i]], with the note that you should then loop over c("2004", "2006"), otherwise your data.frame will end up with 2006 columns (but you might want to avoid using only numbers as column names anyway).

```
ma <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 8)
df <- data.frame(ma)
colnames(df) <- c("2004", "2006")

for (i in c("2004", "2006")) {
  df[[i]] <- my_function(i)
}
```

– Axeman

Comment: Nice. You should probably also post the code that actually works as part of your answer.

Comment: @BenBolker. Very good point. I will edit the answer.